# Host Header in IIS

Tags: dns, iis-6

I have some enquiry about IIS6 and host header that I will like to seek advice.

I have server A that is hosting an application and i have a domain registered( www. test. com ). I have another application that is residing in server B.

I will like to ask whether is there any setting in IIS 6 that I can configure that when i click on (www. test. com) and in the website i have a hyperlink to direct the page to the files in server B. Can I use the host header to name as (www.test1.com) in server B but the www.test1.com is not registered?

Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This question might be better answered on [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com).

www.test.com and www.test1.com are different domain names. They have to both be registered on a DNS server and have A record or CNAME record using the IP address of each of your servers.

www.test.com -> server A
www.test1.com -> server B

Once registered they can either have DNS entries that either both point to server A or server B or where www.test.com points to server A and www.test1.com points to server B.

In IIS host headers are used to allow the IIS to know which application(s) use which domain(s) if you host more than one domain on your serverr. One application can have multiple host header references, e.g. www.test.com and test.com and secure.test.com. Or it can have just one.